# how to count the same string value in txtbox using vbnet

Tags: vb.net

what the solution for this code that count the same string value using
VB.net

My Code:

```
    Public Sub du30_langMalakas()
        While txtb_Win.Text = "YOU WIN"
            Dcount = +1
            If Dcount = 3 Then
                btn_duterte.Visible = True
            End If
        End While
        While txtb_Win.Text = "AI WIN"
            Dcount = +1
            If Dcount = 3 Then
                btn_duterte.Visible = True
            End If
        End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Since there is nothing in the While loop that changes the Text of the textbox, this loop will either never run or will be an infinite loop.

Comment: OK I See it, But What the options To come Up with this problem

Comment: Regex has a matches method

Comment: Are you trying to find out how many times "You Win" is found in the TextBox?

Comment: Yes, but they count 3 consecutively so if the 3 consecutuve string in the textbox is true then print